# A better graphic card for my laptop?

Tags: 12.04, ati, dell

I have an old Dell Studio 1558 laptop, now I would like to change the VGA card and I hope you can show me what is the best for my Ubuntu Laptop. [Here is the output of dmidecode command](http://pastebin.com/3t1DnhJC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant' generally change the video cards on a laptop.You can on a desktop. Have a look at e.g http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/295930-15-dell-studio-1558-upgrade-graphics-card

There are ways to connect a graphics card EXTERNALLY to a laptop e.g. http://www.techradar.com/news/computing-components/graphics-cards/how-to-make-an-external-laptop-graphics-adaptor-915616